# Pegar um valor armazenado em um link .html

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

O Site https://thingspeak.com/channels/116346/field/1/last.html retorna um valor e gostaria de saber como implementa-lo e atualiza-lo, por exemplo, a cada 5 minutos.

Atualmente estou fazendo com o seguinte Script

```
<script>
    function loadTemp() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://thingspeak.com/channels/116346/field/1/last.html", true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Mas estou usando um botao para mostrar esse valor

```
<div class="panel-body">
 <div class="text-center">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="loadTemp()">Temperatura</button>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
<p class="text-center" id="temp">TempºC</p>
</div>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: estas a usar jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Para correr a cada 5 minutos precisas de usar `setInterval` ou `setTimeout` a ser invocado dentro da função loadTemp.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
function loadTemp() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            temp.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText + ' ºC';
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://thingspeak.com/channels/116346/field/1/last.html", true);
    xhttp.send();
    return loadTemp;
}
var temp = document.getElementById("temp");
setInterval(loadTemp(), 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Uso `loadTemp()` como argumento do `setInterval` pois assim invoca a função diretamente no inicio. Depois como tenho `return loadTemp;` no final da função o argumento deixado ao `setInterval` é a função corrida a cada 5 minutos. 5 minutos == 5 x 60 segundos x 1000 milisegundos.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ath99L64/

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer com setInterval, ou setTimeout recursivo:

Com setInterval:

```
<p id="temp"></p>
...
<script>
    function loadTemp() {
    alert('atualização');
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://thingspeak.com/channels/116346/field/1/last.html", true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
    loadTemp();
    setInterval(loadTemp, 5000); // aqui o tempo é em milisecondos, pus 5 secs só a titulo de exemplo... para 5 minutos seriam 1000 * 60 * 5 = 300000
</script>
```

Exemplo no [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zo34xs20/1/)

Mas muitas vezes é melhor fazer com setTimeout recursivo, pois visto que estamos a fazer uma requisição externa umas vezes umas demoram mais que outras e o setInterval já vai estar definido mesmo antes da requisição anterior ter sido finalizada.

Ou seja, suponha que temos o setInterval em 5 segundos, este intervalo é sempre executado (5 secs), a primeira requisição foi feita e demorou 3 secondos a obter resposta, dali a 2 secs a segunda execução do setInterval
é realizada e só demora 1... E por aí em diante, isto vai resultar atropelos e respostas ao mesmo tempo etc...

Para garantir que a proxima requisição será sempre feita 5 secs (neste caso) depois de obtermos uma resposta fazemos:

```
<p id="temp"></p>
...
<script>
    function loadTemp() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            alert('successo no request');
            document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            setTimeout(loadTemp, 5000); // aqui o tempo é em milisecondos, pus 5 secs só a titulo de exemplo... para 5 minutos seriam 1000 * 60 * 5 = 300000
        }
        else if (xhttp.status >= 500){
            alert('erro no request');
            setTimeout(loadTemp, 5000); // aqui chamamos outravez no caso de falha, para a próxima pode ser que seja bem sucedida e atualize
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://thingspeak.com/channels/116346/field/1/last.html", true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
    loadTemp();
</script>
```

Exemplo no [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zo34xs20/9/)

Comment: Fazendo `setTimeout`  recursivo é melhor invocar o próximo `setTimeout`  mesmo que não seja um 200. Senão caso um pedido falhe o `setTimeout`  nunca mais é chamado.

Comment: Tem razão. Mas creio que pode sempre chamar nos dois casos, sucesso e falha. Se falhar é chamado na mesma

Comment: Pois, como está só é chamado se o ajax der `200`. Caso não encontre e der um `400` ou `500` o proximo `setTimeout` nunca vai ser chamado.